# Can you ever touch the ball with two hands between bounces while dribbling?

Tags: rules, basketball, collegiate

Look at [this video](https://youtu.be/y_AjX1pZj_E?t=6m42s) at 6:42. NBA rules today state that this is not legal. Is this legal under NFHS/NCAA rules?

He tosses the ball behind his back with his right hand and then continues his dribble with his left hand. At no point does he ever touch the ball with both hands simultaneously. Let's assume he doesn't carry (go under) the ball with his right hand on that behind-the-back toss.

Excerpt from the 2017-2018 NCAA rulebook:

> Art. 4. The dribble ends when:
>
> a. The dribbler catches or carries/palms the ball by allowing it to come to rest in one or both hands;
>
> b. The dribbler touches the ball with both hands simultaneously;
>
> c. An opponent bats the ball; or
>
> d. The ball becomes dead

It doesn't look like the rules prohibit this type of move when done well, yet people often say that it's illegal. Are there other rules or interpretations that I'm missing? Please provide any official sources you use in your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [NBA Rules](https://www.nba.com/media/dleague/1314-nba-rule-book.pdf) have more than those four paragraphs

> **Section II—Dribble**
>
> A dribble is movement of the ball, caused by a player in control, who
>   throws or taps the ball to the floor.
>
> a. The dribble ends when the dribbler:
>
> 1. Touches the ball simultaneously with both hands
> 2. Permits the ball to come to rest while he is in control of it
> 3. Tries for a field goal
> 4. Throws a pass
> 5. **Touches the ball more than once while dribbling, before it touches the floor**
> 6. Loses control
> 7. Allows the ball to become dead

The player violated the 5th paragraph by touching the ball two times before it touched the floor again. Since the [NCAA rules](https://ncaambb.arbitersports.com/Groups/104883/Library/files/BR15.pdf) don't mention this it is perfectly legal there (assuming the ball doesn't rest on his palm as you've stated).